# Android Layout alignment issues

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I have a layout which i need to make it look alike Image B. But it comes like Image A. Am i messing too much with Linear or Relative Layouts ? Also i have footbar buttons inside Table Layout which works fine in all other screens but for this it doesn't shows up. Below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dip" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inboxtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="#f2f2f2"
            android:textColor="#444444"
            android:text="New message"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deleteheader"
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/emailsender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sendicon"
            android:text="Sync" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444444"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:hint="Select Subject"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColor="#4a82ae"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mailcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:hint="Enter Content Here"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:textColorLink="@color/white" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_foldout_menu"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dropdown_textview"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="1dip"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt0"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Subject 1"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#cccccc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Subject 2"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#cccccc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Subject 3"
                android:textSize="17dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:background="#cccccc" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="Subject 4"
                android:textSize="17dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/support"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteheader"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inboxtext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:text="New message"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteheader"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/emailsender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sendicon"
        android:text="Sync" />
</LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:hint="Select Subject"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#4a82ae"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mailcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:hint="Enter Content Here"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:textColorLink="#ffffff" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/support"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Try with code and for Selecting message You can use pop up.

If you want do by your method then try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       android:src="@drawable/back"  />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteheader"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inboxtext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="New message"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/deleteheader"
        android:layout_width="2dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="15dip"
        android:paddingTop="15dip" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/emailsender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sendicon"
        android:text="Sync" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dropdown_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:hint="Select Subject"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#4a82ae"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#f2f2f2" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mailcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Enter Content Here"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColorLink="#ffffff" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_foldout_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dropdown_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt0"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Subject 1"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#cccccc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Subject 2"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#cccccc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Subject 3"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#cccccc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dropdown_alt3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_selector"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Subject 4"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Support"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/support"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#092435"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Messages"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

If your requirement is different or any thing else then comment.

Comment: Crooper - Thanks but for second code u posted it is giving me errors, i guess some of layouts we haven't closed. Can you check back. Then i shall try

Comment: @user45678 Check now.

Comment: That was pretty good. But still i cannot find the footer buttons which are there in TableLayout. Should i again use one more relative layout for that ?

Comment: I got it the height of Relative Layout was "fill_parent". I changed to "wrap_content". Its working now...Thanks...May be if u can make those changes in code...i shall accept so that our readers wouldn't get misguided...Just change "android:layout_height="wrap_content" in a "RelativeLayout" above "FrameLayout"

Comment: In my code there is no Frame layout and i have taken relative layout with height of 0dp and weight 1;